# Recordings mark for deletion after X weeks and X count based on a business

Tags: mysql

I am having troubles writing (what I think is) a complex query. I have a recordings table that holds all active recordings on my site. I wish to keep recordings for a given X number of weeks before they are marked "marked for deletion". Also I want to only store X number of recordings for a particular "recs_bus_id" or business. Each business is only allowed to have X number of recordings for a account before marked for deletion and the timestamp for recs_mark_deletion_time is also updated

Here is my problem, I don't know how to do this without doing a insane amount of queries

**RECORDINGS**

```
recs_id  |  recs_insert_time | recs_title | recs_bus_id | recs_mark_deletion_time | recs_mark_deletion
```

**BUSINESSES**

```
bus_id | bus_rec_save_weeks | bus_max_rec_save_count
```

- bus_max_rec_save_count is the total number of recordings that business is allowed save

Right now I am doing this for get the recordings to mark for deletion

```
SELECT * FROM recordings JOIN businesses ON Recording.recs_bus_id = Business.bus_id AND Recording.recs_insert_time < NOW() - INTERVAL Business.bus_rec_save_weeks WEEK
```

- I then just loop through the resultset and delete mark each for deletion

I do not know how to get the resultset of the records that are outside of the top "bus_max_rec_save_count" based on a "bus_id" to mark for deletion.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `update` to update the flag:

```
update recordings JOIN
       businesses
       ON Recording.recs_bus_id = Business.bus_id AND
          Recording.recs_insert_time < NOW() - INTERVAL Business.bus_rec_save_weeks WEEK
  set recordins.MarkForDeletion = 1;
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how I could combine this with the bus_max_rec_save_count?

Comment: @Sixthpoint . . . I am unclear on how this is used.  Could you modify the question to explain it better?  In particular, are you trying to prevent certain recordings from being marked (and if so, which ones)?  Or, are you trying to mark additional records (and if so, which ones)?

Comment: I have business who are only allowed X number of recording for there account. So after they have X number of recordings, it starts marking the oldest ones by recs_insert_time (timestamp) to markfordeletion. I am trying to prevent the newest ones from being marked for deletion in this case.